# Why is both ./tags and tags present in the Vim 'tags' option?

Tags: vim

If I execute `:set tags?` in Vim, I get the following output.

```
  tags=./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS
```

If I execute the `:help 'tags'` in Vim, I get the following documentation.

```
                                                *'tags'* *'tag'* *E433*
'tags' 'tag'            string  (default "./tags,tags", when compiled with
                                |+emacs_tags|: "./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS")
                        global or local to buffer |global-local|
        Filenames for the tag command, separated by spaces or commas.  To
        include a space or comma in a file name, precede it with a backslash
        (see |option-backslash| about including spaces and backslashes).
        When a file name starts with "./", the '.' is replaced with the path
        of the current file.  But only when the 'd' flag is not included in
        'cpoptions'.  Environment variables are expanded |:set_env|.  Also see
        |tags-option|.
        "*", "**" and other wildcards can be used to search for tags files in
        a directory tree.  See |file-searching|.  {not available when compiled
        without the |+path_extra| feature}
        The |tagfiles()| function can be used to get a list of the file names
        actually used.
        If Vim was compiled with the |+emacs_tags| feature, Emacs-style tag
        files are also supported.  They are automatically recognized.  The
        default value becomes "./tags,./TAGS,tags,TAGS", unless case
        differences are ignored (MS-Windows).  |emacs-tags|
        The use of |:set+=| and |:set-=| is preferred when adding or removing
        file names from the list.  This avoids problems when a future version
        uses another default.
        {Vi: default is "tags /usr/lib/tags"}
```

I want to know why both `./tags` and 'tags` are present in this option?

The documentation says, `When a file name starts with "./", the '.' is replaced with the path of the current file.` So `./tags` seem to behave similar to `tags`, or am I mistaken?

What is the difference between `./tags` and `tags` in this option?

Comment: If you're interested in using Vim better, do checkout [vi.se].

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The path of the current file is not necessarily the same as the current working directory. With `tags` the latter directory is used, with `./tags`, the former. The difference is explained in [`:h tags-option`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/tagsrch.txt.html#tags-option):

```
When a tag file name starts with "./", the '.' is replaced with the path of
the current file.  This makes it possible to use a tags file in the directory
where the current file is (no matter what the current directory is).  The idea
of using "./" is that you can define which tag file is searched first: In the
current directory ("tags,./tags") or in the directory of the current file
("./tags,tags").

For example: 
        :set tags=./tags,tags,/home/user/commontags

In this example the tag will first be searched for in the file "tags" in the
directory where the current file is.  Next the "tags" file in the current
directory.  If it is not found there, then the file "/home/user/commontags"
will be searched for the tag.
```

For example, consider the following directory tree:

```
.
├── project2
│   └── tags
└── project1
    └── tags
```

And you do:

```
cd project1; vim ../project2/foo.c
```

Then `project2/tags` will be used first, and then `project1/tags` (assuming you don't have `autochdir` set, or similar shenanigans aren't at work).